# Is it possible to update all objects in Java without loop?

Tags: java, class, oop

I have a employee class and I want all employee's age to be increased by one with one method without looping. Is that possible?

```
class Employee{
    Employee(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    String name;
    int age;
    static void NextYear()
    {
        //age++;
        // will increase all ages by 1 
    }
    
    void increaseAge() // I don't want this method
    {
        age++;
    }
    
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(23);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(34);
        
        Employee.NextYear(); // want increase all ages by one 
        
        System.out.println("e1 age " + e1.age); // need 24
        System.out.println("e2 age " + e2.age); // need 35
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not possible.  Some code, somewhere, will need to loop to achieve this.

Comment: Is there a way that does not seems like a loop?

Comment: Better store the birth year/day (which never changes) and calculate the age dynamically in getAge()

Comment: Why are loops banned? Is this a homework question for a class that hasn't taught loops yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using static field, but i don't recommend this.

Why this approach is not recommended?

Static variables are much more difficult to test and require extra attention and additional synchronization with a multithreaded environment. In such a simple scenario, you would introduce unnecessary complexity.

```
private static class Employee {

    private static int offset;

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    private Employee(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age + offset;
    }

    public static void nextYear() {
        offset++;
    }
}

Employee e1 = new Employee("e1", 23);
Employee e2 = new Employee("e2", 34);

Employee.nextYear();

System.out.println("e1 age " + e1.getAge()); // 24
System.out.println("e2 age " + e2.getAge()); // 35
```